# IE9 FCKEditor toolbar doesn't show until refresh page

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-9, fckeditor

I have an FCKEditor with a toolbar on an ASPX page that I use as a member review entry form.  This has worked quite well until IE9.  Now when the page first comes up it doesn't work right and the FCKEditor toolbar is not visible.  If I refresh the page it works fine.

I'm not sure what code to show here, this is what I have on my ASPX page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" Namespace="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" TagPrefix="FCKeditorV2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <table width=580>
    <tr><td colspan="2">
...
        Enter your review here:<br />
        <FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor Width="580px" Height="400px" id="FCKeditor2" BasePath="~/FCKeditor/"  runat="server">
        </FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor>
```

Here is a page that demonstrates the problem:

http://www.ourlaughingplace.com/aspx/review.aspx?parent=0&cat=attraction&from=at&thingId=PDL

Note: the toolbar comes up just fine everytime under FireFox.

Comment: Please remove the {solved} text from the title and the answer portion from your question, post that portion as a real answer, and then accept it.

Comment: Ok, didn't realize that is the protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research (and a lack of responses here) I came to the conclusion that the first thing to do is upgrade to the new version CKEditor 3.6.2 ASP.NET control. After downloading, installing and futzing around with it I was able to get the new editor working in place of the old -- and now it comes up correclty under IE9 -- Problem Solved!

For future readers reference, this is the link to CKEditor:

http://cksource.com/ckeditor